# Write two variables of different type in c++

Tags: c++, winforms

I know the question might seem a little stupid but i tried everything and don't know how to make it, i am trying to write two different types in a message box, one if them is a string and the other is a character like this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

and i am trying to add a string before buffer and tried

"string " + buffer

"string " << buffer

but neither worked. thanks for all repliers all really appreciated

**EDIT**

---

my real problem is when i try to make it as string and display it in message box i get an error cannot convert from string to LPCSTR

Comment: It would help if you told us what type `buffer` is. `std::string`? `char*`? Also `"string " + buffer` and `"string " << buffer` are both invalid code; it wouldn't be a bad idea for you to show the actual code you tried.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn some C++, specifically how to use `std::string`.

Comment: @user3407319: read my answer again, especially the part with the `c_str()` function.

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::string` and you'll be fine. I guess `buffer` is **not** of type `char` but rather `char const *`, isn't it? Then you can just use the `+` operator:

```
std::string("string") + buffer;
```

If `MessageBox` takes a `char const *` argument, you can use `std::string`'s `c_str()` member function to pass the string:

```
MessageBox(NULL, (std::string("string") + buffer).c_str(), "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ these are different ways to represent a character string.

The simplest is an `array of characters`.  This is simple and very fast, but the array doesn't have any intelligence so it is easy to overwrite the end of the array (buffer overflow) which is seriously bad.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const int nLength = 24;
    char szBuff[nLength];
    ::strcpy(szBuff, "Hello");   // cpy ==> copy
    ::strcat(szBuff, " World");  // cat ==< concatenate
    std::cout << szBuff << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The standard library provides a class `std::string`.  This class automatically resizes itself, making it more resiliant to errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string sBuff;
    sBuff = "Hello";
    sBuff += " World";
    std::cout << sBuff << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When you call a function, you need to know what sort of string it expects.

If it expects an `std::string` and you give it an array (`const char *`), that is OK as `std::string` is automatically constructed from a char array.

In the reverse case, where a funcgtion expects an array, but gets a std::string, that will generate a compiler error.  Fortunately, the std::string has a function "`c_str()`"

```
int main() 
{
    std::string sStr = "Hello";
    char szArr[24] = "Hello";

    funcA(szArr); // OK
    funcA(sStr);  // OK
    funcB(szArr); // OK
    funcB(sStr);  // Syntax Error
    funcB(sStr.c_str()); // OK

    return 0;
}
```

Now in your case, `MessageBox()` takes a character array (`const char *`) for its second parameter, and I assume that `buffer` is a character array.  You cannot simply join two arrays, but must use `::strcat()`.

```
void ShowMsg(const char *szMsg)
{
    const char *szPrefix = "Error: ";
    const int nLen = 256;
    char szBuff[nLen];

    // make sure buffer is big enough
    assert(strlen(szPrefix) + ::strlen(szMsg) < nLen);

    ::strcpy(szBuff, szPrefix);
    ::strcat(szBuff, szMsg);
    ::MessageBox(NULL, szBuff, "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Now two `std::string`s can be added together like `sPrefix + sMsg` and the result is a `std::string`.  You can even append an array to a `std::string` like `sPrefix + szMsg`, still giving an std::string.  So our `ShowMessage()` function may be simplified.

```
void ShowMsg(const char *szMsg)
{
    std::string sPrefix = "Error: ";

    ::MessageBox(NULL, (sPrefix + szMsg).c_str(), "", 
                 MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Now we've just barely scratched the surface of the complexity of strings.  I suggest that you get up close and personal with a good C++ text and really learn strings before you go too much further.

Comment: You are using char pointer and char array interchangeably here, they are not the same thing. for example when you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer value pointing to the first element of the array

Comment: It is not "MS Windows" which provides the CString class, but the hopelessly outdated MFC library.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - They are not the same thing, but they are interchangable.  As you said, yourself: "when you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer value".  I could have (should have??) spent more time explaining that, but the take-home message was to use the `std::string` in preference to the pointer/array.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - There is also an almost identical ATL implementation of CString.

Comment: @MichaelJ: AFAIK, that was more or less imported directly from MFC. In any case, it's still wrong to say that "MS Windows" provides this. It has nothing to do with the operating system. Not even with VC. That may be clear to you and me, but certainly not to the OP.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - The ATL CString is a complete rewrite, making better use of templates.  The interface is very similar, but not identical.  Anyway, the reference has been removed, lest it offend you further.

Answer (score -3):

Or as a char string (if buffer is a char *)

```
char * Result;
Result = new char (strlen(buffer) + strlen("string") + 1);
sprintf (Result, "string%s", buffer);
MessageBox(NULL, Result, "", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
delete Result;
```

Comment: Why on earth would you ever write that instead of using `std::string`? It's uglier, longer, more complicated, and more error prone. And wrong.

Comment: It's just one other possiblity :)